# Combining Event and an attribute in threepenny-gui

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

I have an `Event String` which I want to `sink` into a textarea. This works fine, but now I want to combine the current value of a checkbox selection to this string.

First I did this by using `checkedChange` of the checkbox which works, but has a problem. If the `checked` value is sinked to the checkbox, there is no checkedChange-Event and the value shown in the textarea isn't updated properly.

I could read the checkbox selection with `get checked` but then I run into problems combining `Event String` and `UI Bool` (or `UI String` as the boolean is going to be transformed to a string).

EDIT: To be more precise, I want to do something like

```
bCombinedValue <- stepper "" eCombinedValue
element textArea # sink UI.text bCombinedValue
```

where `eCombinedValue` has the original `Event String` and the current value of the `checked` attribute of a checkbox.

I could have

```
bCheck <- stepper False $ UI.checkedChange checkBox
```

but this fails if I have

```
element checkBox # sink UI.checked bBool
```

somewhere else (no `UI.checkedChange`).

I can use `show <$> get UI.checked checkBox` but then I would have to combine `Event String` and `UI String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intentional: The `UI.checkedChange` event only triggers when the *user* clicks the checkbox, but *not* when it is set programmatically. The intention is that the `bBool` behavior represents the canonical state of the checkbox and the `UI.checkedChange` event represents request from the user to change it, which may or may not be granted. This allows [bidirectional dataflow](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/blog/2012/03/29-frp-three-principles-bidirectional-gui.html) ([see also](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/threepenny-gui/blob/master/doc%2Fdesign-widgets.md#three-principles-for-representing-mvc-concepts-with-frp)). Admittedly, Threepenny does not strictly follows these ideas just yet.

In your case, I recommend to integrate the `UI.checkedChange` event into the `bBool` behavior to represent the "canonical" state of the checkbox. If that doesn't work, just hack it up with `get UI.checked` and `Reactive.Threepenny.unsafeMapIO`.

Comment: Oh, this was a fairly easy thing in the end. Just changed `bBool` to include the `UI.checkedChange` and it works. Thank you!